# Gnome-font-manager missing on GNOME3?

Tags: gnome

I'm using the GNOME3 PPA. The gnome-font-manager is missing in the new gnome-control-panel. Is this going to be added some day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add it yourself.

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install font-manager
```

Comment: Is that the "official" gnome font manager?
Anyway, that made the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No. It's not "official", maybe someday. The current version is adequate for my needs and better than the alternatives, but not something that's even close to finished.

It's undergoing another re-write at this point. The goal is cleaner code, interface improvements and desktop integration. So it might be a little while. ;-)

Note: My opinion may be a little biased since I'm the author...

[Project Homepage](http://code.google.com/p/font-manager/)